# Pytorch: RuntimeError: zero-dimensional tensor (at position 0) cannot be concatenated

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, tensor, pytorch-geometric

I have two tensors

```
# losses_q
tensor(0.0870, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
# this_loss_q
tensor([0.0874], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

when I am trying to concat them, pytorch raises an error:

```
losses_q = torch.cat((losses_q, this_loss_q), dim=0)

RuntimeError: zero-dimensional tensor (at position 0) cannot be concatenated
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`losses_q` is zero dimensional so can't be concatenated with anything. You can reshape it into a one dimensional tensor before concatenation.

```py
losses_q = torch.cat((losses_q.reshape(1), this_loss_q), dim=0)
```